# How to check all elements in row/column clicked, Bingo game

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onlyandrewn/b18b4bza/

I'm making a bingo card and currently it keeps a count of every time a square has been clicked. However, I'm lost on how to make it so that when five squares in a row, column or on a diagonal are clicked for a Bingo, it knows that it's a win as opposed to any random five squares on the card.

Would I have to give each square on the card an #id and then have arrays that say if squares 1,2,3,4,5 have been clicked = a Bingo?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Election Bingo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico"> -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Political Zinger</h1>
<button class="print">Print</button>
<button class="again">Play again</button>

<div class="congrats">
    <p>WINNER!</p>
</div><!-- /.congrats -->

<div class="bingo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="square"><p>Chrissy Teigen cries</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Host makes a quick change</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>'I love you!'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>'Merci' or 'Gracias'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Attempt at re-creating the 'Ellen selfie'</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square"><p>A Weinstein is thanked</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Jennifer Lawrence trips</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Half-joking mention of nominee diversity</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>'This is heavy!'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>A shout-out for winner's kids (who should be sleeping)</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square"><p>Joke about number of British nominees</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Award accepted posthumously</p></div>
        <div class="logo"><p>Logo</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Joke about the Sony hack</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Winner mentions fellow nominees</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square"><p>'I'd like to thank the academy ...'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>'Je Suis Charlie'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>The show goes over three hours</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Camera pans to George and Amal</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Winner talks over orchestra</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square"><p>Winner thanks agent or manager</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Winner forgets to thank spouse</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Host makes a borderline-offensive joke</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>Presenters have a scripted 'disagreement'</p></div>
        <div class="square"><p>NPH performs a music number</p></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.bingo -->


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### scripts.js

```
$(function() {
    // Play again, removes all previously clicked
    $('.again').click(function(){
        $('.square').removeClass('clicked');
    });

    // var newNum = Math.floor(Math.random);

    // Toggle clicked and not clicked
    $('.square').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });

    // Count the number of squares clicked
    $('.square').data('clicked', 0)
        .click(function(){
            var counter = $(this).data('clicked');
            $(this).data('clicked', counter ++);
            console.log(counter);
        })
});
```

Comment: My initial hunch is yes, you'll need to assign each item a unique ID so that you can associate it with a location.  A `A1,B1` row/col format seems most logical and you could either manually enter all the winning options, or do it programmatically/conditionally based on the ID's (ie if all 5 selected are A, or 2, or the numbers are all sequential, etc).

Comment: @Mike Could you expand on your answer with a code sample.

Comment: I'm not in a position where I could make a function code sample, but your best bet is to do something like this:  Create an array of all the winning combinations (omit the center tile, as it's assumed).  When the user clicks your square, append the ID to an array and compare that array to your array of winning combinations.  If existing = desired then you have a winner.  I'll try to provide code later, if no one else jumps in.

Comment: And don't forget to clear your selected array if the user opts to "play again."

Comment: Had a few minutes open up.  See answer below with sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, there's more than one way to skin a cat, especially with a unique situation like this.  That said, here's one approach.

Updated JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/b18b4bza/5/

Start by assigning a unique ID to each cell.  I've chosen an "A1,B2" format similar to a spreadsheet, where letters and numbers represent columns and rows, respectively.

### index.html

```
<div class="bingo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a1"><p>Chrissy Teigen cries</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b1"><p>Host makes a quick change</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c1"><p>'I love you!'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d1"><p>'Merci' or 'Gracias'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e1"><p>Attempt at re-creating the 'Ellen selfie'</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a2"><p>A Weinstein is thanked</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b2"><p>Jennifer Lawrence trips</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c2"><p>Half-joking mention of nominee diversity</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d2"><p>'This is heavy!'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e2"><p>A shout-out for winner's kids (who should be sleeping)</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a3"><p>Joke about number of British nominees</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b3"><p>Award accepted posthumously</p></div>
        <div class="logo"><p>Logo</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d3"><p>Joke about the Sony hack</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e3"><p>Winner mentions fellow nominees</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a4"><p>'I'd like to thank the academy ...'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b4"><p>'Je Suis Charlie'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c4"><p>The show goes over three hours</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d4"><p>Camera pans to George and Amal</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e4"><p>Winner talks over orchestra</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="square" id="a5"><p>Winner thanks agent or manager</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="b5"><p>Winner forgets to thank spouse</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="c5"><p>Host makes a borderline-offensive joke</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="d5"><p>Presenters have a scripted 'disagreement'</p></div>
        <div class="square" id="e5"><p>NPH performs a music number</p></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.bingo -->
```

Then update your Javascript with a few additions:

### scripts.js

```
$(function() {

    // Set winning combinations to array
    var winners = [
        ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'],
        ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5'],
        ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'],
        ['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'],
        ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5'],
        ['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1'],
        ['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2'],
        ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3'],
        ['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4'],
        ['a5','b5','c5','d5','e5'],
        ['a1','b2','c3','d4','e5'],
        ['a5','b4','c3','d2','e1']
    ];
    var possibleWinners = winners.length;

    // Initialize selected array with c3 freebie
    var selected = ['c3'];

    // Play again, removes all previously clicked
    $('.again').click(function(){
        $('.square').removeClass('clicked');
        selected = ['c3'];
    });

    // Toggle clicked and not clicked
    $('.square').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

        // Push clicked object ID to 'selected' array
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));

        // Compare winners array to selected array for matches
        for(var i = 0; i < possibleWinners; i++) {
            var cellExists = 0;

            for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if($.inArray(winners[i][j], selected) > -1) {
                    cellExists++;
                }
            }

            // If all 5 winner cells exist in selected array alert success message
            if(cellExists == 5) {
                alert('Winner!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Count the number of squares clicked
    $('.square').data('clicked', 0)
        .click(function(){
            var counter = $(this).data('clicked');
            $(this).data('clicked', counter ++);
            console.log(counter);
        })

});
```

What I've done to the JS, in order of appearance:

1. Create a "winners" array of all the possible winning combinations
2. Create a "selected" array, prepopulated with cell C3, since that's a freebie
3. Clear the "selected" array if someone opts to play again
4. Compare your "winners" array to your "selected" array and if there are 5 matches (all of the winning numbers) then alert that there's a winner.  You'd obviously replace the alert with whatever action you wanted to take when there's a winner...

The details of the array comparison are admittedly a bit clunky, but hopefully the concept will at least get you off to a good start.

Additionally, this solution is not particularly scalable, especially with regard to the "winners" array.  You could theoretically determine winners using conditional statements, but there is only a small number of possible winning combinations in this case so my example is just hard coded.